# Do the addresses of variables, declared just after each other, precede each other?

Tags: c++, variables, memory-address

I am learning about **c++ pointers** and I have the following question.

When I declare for example three variables like this:

```
int a = 0, b = 1, c = 2;
```

Will there variable have addresses that precede each other... like when the address of `a` ends, does the address of `b` start immediately?

Additionally, please provide me with some links of tutorials or some books so I can learn about how computer works with memory (bit, byte...), because I do not quite understand how the computer, variables and data work and I can't a useful link anywhere.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: no matter if the addresses follow one another, you should NOT relie on that for your code. Remember: Another compiler or another version of your compiler might handle that differently.

Comment: `I do not quite understand how the computer, variables and data work`. To understand this learn some Assembly language basics.

Comment: You are really asking a question about the inner workings of a c++ compiler and about the details of how a variable is turned into a memory location.  This is an interesting, curiosity driven question.  If you eventually work with embedded systems where memory management is critical, those details may be of importance, but for most programming applications, you will not need to worry about those details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon compiler how it assign address's for variable.

In your case the address's might be sequential or might not be.

You can simply verify from the code as :

```
#include"iostream"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 1, c = 2;

    cout<<"Address of A : "<<&a<<endl<<"Address of B : "<<&b<<endl<<"Address of C : "<<&c<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So if you need to play around the address of variable, always take a pointer of that type and then use pointer to access or change the variable.

Example :

```
int *p_a = &a;
int *p_b = &b;
int *p_c = &c;
```

Comment: So, as I understand, arrays are spacial, because their addresses are sequential, am I right?

BTW, Thanks for good answer,I really appreciate :)

Comment: Your welcome....Yes array are special and the variable stored in Array is at sequential memory address.

Answer (score 1):

It is up to the compiler. May be better for the compiler to rearrange them according to the rest of the method.

Anyway - why worry?

Comment: "why worry?".  Mild, academic curiosity about these things is good for C and C++.  One of the main advantages of these languages is that they do expose what you can otherwise access only in assembly.  So knowing about that stuff is good.  *Worrying* about it obsessively is a problem.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala - There are a lot of papers on compiler technology. One springs to mind is this - http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/technology-briefs/intel-labs-closing-ninja-gap-paper.pdf - but it is not a question