# pointers from heap and instances from stack C++

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

My purpose is to determine if I should deallocate using delete a variable to a pointer stored in a linked list...

I had the idea to consider that any pointer allocated in the heap will be strictly superior to the first "new" used... and that any variable stored in the stack at any kevel of any procedure call will be inferior to the first pointer allocated with "new"...

I tried :

```
void main()

     { int A;
       int *b = new int;

       cout << &A << '\t' << b;
     }
```

on my computer, it outputs :

```
0x0019FE9C     0x0236542C
```

that is `b > a` .... so looks like correct on Windows 10...

Is this an illusion or really correct and portable ?

Comment: This is an illusion. C++ is hard. You are looking for a shortcut to proper memory management. There are very few shortcuts in C++ and this isn't one of them.

Comment: You cannot compare pointers that are not from the same array, it's Undefined Behaviour. Anything could happen in such a program. You should `delete` what you have `new`'ed and `delete[]` what you have `new[]`'ed, that the only rule.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen afaik its not undefined, but merely unspecified. `std::less` even has some mechanism to compare pointers just fine

Comment: Order of address is not guaranteed by the c++ standard. [Is the order of memory addresses of successively declared variables always descending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438216/is-the-order-of-memory-addresses-of-successively-declared-variables-always-desce) and [Do the addresses of variables, declared just after each other, precede each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633517/do-the-addresses-of-variables-declared-just-after-each-other-precede-each-othe)

Comment: You should deallocate with `delete` only if allocated with `new`. If you do not have that information, you have to track it manually. Forget any address-based heuristics, that is just landmine waiting to be stepped on. Pointer-tagging could be an option though if you are desperate.

Comment: you shouldnt run into the situation that you have a pointer and you dont know if it is an owning one or not in the first place (owning = one that needs to be deleted at some point). If you do run into this situation you have a flaw in your design.

Comment: Don't store pointers in a linked list. If you need pointer semantics a better choice is one of the smart pointers that C++ provides. Those do not need deleting.

Comment: Side note, if you're new to C++. Just stay away from `new/delete` for a long time. If you have a linked list use [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)  and you will not need any pointers at all! std::list will handle all the memory allocation/deallocation of your contained type for you.

Comment: I can understand the non portability to Unix or others, but due to the management of pointers under DOS (malloc...) or Windows (GlobalAlloc...), until you don't use the Locking Memory System proposed by Windows, how not to be sure the above will be wrong...?

Comment: unless you mention it explicitly, we assume quesitons tagged as `c++` are about standard portable c++. I mean you ask "Is this ... portable?" but now it seems like you need to know if it works on some specific system?

Comment: you are so right : * should be tagged for c, * I need to know if it is only valid on ms systems

Answer (score 1):

Your strategy is flawed for several reasons.

Even if you could reliably compare two pointer that do not point to element of the same array (you cannot) there is following issue:

```
#include <iostream>
    
int main() {
    int *b = new int;
    int *c = b;    
    std::cout << b << '\t' << c << '\n';

}
```

`b` and `c` have the same value. If you use only the value of the pointer to decide whether to use `delete` or not, then you either delete both or neither of them.

If you `delete` both you invoke undefined behavior. If you delete neither of them you have a leak.

The fundamental issue here is false expectations about raw pointers. Raw pointers point somewhere, and that's it. Hence, if you need to manage lifetime of some object then a raw pointer alone cannot do that.

Do not use raw owning pointers. Use `std::list`, `std::unique_ptr` and/or other facilities the standard library offers. In rare cases you need to write your own lifetime managing code, then it must be concentrated to a simple RAII class that manages the lifetime of an object but nothing else.

Some buzzwords for further reading: rule of zero, smart pointers, ownership, no raw owning pointers, RAII.

Comment: " In rare cases you need to write your own lifetime managing code" ... I do agree with you, but in this case, code is written from long time ago and cannot be ported to VCL. but is functional under msdos, win31, win95, win98, winnt, win2000, win7, win8, win10... lol ... also under wine (linux).... I really compare two pointers, one one the stack and the other on the heap.... heap is managed bby std::new and std::delete... Is there a way to invalidate &_stack < _heap where _stack is declared as int and _heap as int * ?

Comment: @DavidHarouche I am a bit confused now. Actually it appears that the quesiton is a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You ask about portability of comparing pointers via `<` but your real quesiton should be about some legacy code that for some reason cannot be ported to VCL. I suggest you to open a new quesiton where you tell us about your real issue (not only the idea you had to solve that issue)

Comment: This is the point I reach... A pointer is a unique long integer that points to memory location... right ? If one variable is allocated on the stack (somewhere in my code) and another was allocated on the heap... what is a clean relationship between these 2 long integers that are &(from stack) and (from heap) ?

Comment: "A pointer is a unique long integer that points to memory location." (generally) false.

Comment: "what is a clean relationship between these 2 long integers that are &(from stack) and (from heap) ?"   (portably:)  none

Comment: @DavidHarouche dont try to make generalization based on what you observe on one implementation. Thats very misleading. I think rather than trying to generalize you should focus on what you actually need and ask about that.

Comment: So I will suppose that there is no way to know if  given pointer was from stack or heap...

Comment: @DavidHarouche *"no way to know if given pointer was from stack or heap..."* Generally there is no need to know that in C++. C++ has smart pointer etc.

Comment: @DavidHarouche I am actually certain that on some systems there is a way to tell if a pointer is from stack or heap IF you know on what system you are on. In standard portable c++ there is no way. In your question you try to draw general conclusions from what you observe in windows and that is bound to fail.

Comment: There it is : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263647/objects-in-smalltalk-and-c